# Sum of infinite series $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{b_n^2(1+b_n)}$ where $b_n=\operatorname{round}(\sqrt{2n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm stuck with this problem of finding sum of series:

$\sum_{n=3}^\infty a_n$ where

- $a_n=b_n^{-2}(b_n+1)^{-1},$
- $b_n=\operatorname{round}(\sqrt{2n}),$
- round is a function that rounds to the closest integer.

That's one of the tasks which were given to me (as a way to prepare to the math contest at uni), including the answer which is $\frac5{12}.$

I've tried applying method of undetermined coefficients but all I get is a no-solution equation system like this:
$A=1$;
$2B=0$;
$\sqrt2A=0$.

So I suppose I have to use smth else but I really don't know what exactly. Any tips?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What's the connection between $x,a_n$ and your sum?  More broadly, why would you expect your sum to have a sensible closed form solution?

Comment: If $x = \text{round}(\sqrt{2n})$ and $a_n= x^{-2}(x+1)^{-1}$, then $a_n \ne \frac{1}{2n+\sqrt{2n}^3}$. Why did you simplify as if the $\text{round}$ function is not there?

Comment: @lulu well. as you can see I sum $a_n$ which equals to $x^{-2}(x+1)^{-1}$ while x equals to $\sqrt{2n}$ (let's leave out the 'round' function for now). So as a result sum of $a_n$ turns to the $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{2n+\sqrt{2n}^3}$. That's how they're connected. And I expect this to have a sum bc I have an answer which is ${\frac{5}{12}}$. I simply don't understand how to reach it.

Comment: @jjagmath Sorry, I was trying to find the solution without the round function at first. Didn't expect the answers to differ much.

Comment: I don't get $\frac 5{12}$.  Or, more precisely, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B1%2F%282n%2Bsqrt%28%282n%29%5E3%29%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+3%2C+infinity%7D%5D) does not get $\frac 5{12}$.

Comment: Those are completely different questions, removing the round function gives you a way more harder series

Comment: @AnneBauval That's one of the tasks which were given to me as a way to prepare to the math contest at uni and it has an answer so it should be correct and it takes round into account

Comment: Nor is that the right answer using the Round function, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B1%2F%282n%2BRound%5Bsqrt%28%282n%29%5E3%29%5D%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+3%2C+10%5E4%7D%5D)

Comment: @lulu That's not the series with the round function

Comment: @jjagmath oh ok, then i don't understand how to calculate everything with this function. I mean, how it should affect my calculations?

Comment: @jjagmath  What do you mean?  I have attached links to both computations, with and without Round. Or at least I meant to.  [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B1%2F%282n%2BRound%5Bsqrt%28%282n%29%5E3%29%5D%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+3%2C+10%5E4%7D%5D) is Round again.

Comment: @jjagmath  Or maybe the cube should have been taken outside Round (who knows?).  That one is closer at least, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B1%2F%282n%2BRound%5Bsqrt%28%282n%29%29%5D%5E3%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+3%2C+10%5E5%7D%5D).

Comment: @lulu It might be because you don't use round with the first $\sqrt{2n}$ which simplified to 2n in my calculations

Comment: Please edit your post to ask the question you intended to ask, not some hybrid.  As it is, I'm just guessing as to what is intended.  Note that you should easily be able to modify my WA computations to do whatever you want.  Of course, the system doesn't seem to be able to cope with the infinite version, but $10^5$ should be very close.

Comment: @lulu With the round function, the series term is $\frac{1}{round(\sqrt{2n})^2(1+round(\sqrt{2n}))}$ which DO approach numerically to $5/12$

Comment: @lulu Thanks, I'll try to use it, however the problem with WA - it calculates, but it doesn't explain how to calculate. that's why i posted a question here. And i don't really understand what's so confusing about my question - basically i posted a math problem from the book.

Comment: What's confusing is that you are blending multiple questions together.  Some of the questions involve rounding, some of them don't.  It's hard to disentangle them.

Comment: @lulu Zwi didn't blend questions, but naively removed the round function, thinking that it would make much difference.

Comment: Hint:  the sequence $a_n=\text{Round}(\sqrt {2n})^2+\text{Round}(\sqrt {2n})^3$ is fairly simple.  It's just $\{2,12,12,36,36,36,80,80,80,80,150,\cdots\}$ and $\{2,12,36,80, 150, \cdots\}$ is just $n^2(n+1)$.  That allows you to simplify the sum.  You are basically just left with $\sum \frac 1{n(n+1)}$ which is straightforward.

Comment: @lulu Right, sorry about that, that was my mistake removing the round function! Thank you for the hint, i think i almost got it now :)

Comment: Note:  you should actually prove that the sequence is what I claimed it was.  All I did was to compute the first $50$ terms or so.  I didn't try to prove that the pattern held indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $b_1=1,b_2=2,b_3=2.$
- For any integers $n,m\ge2,$ $b_n=m$ iff $m-\frac12<\sqrt{2n}<m+\frac12$ i.e. iff $m^2-m+1\le2n\le m^2+m.$
- Given $m,$ there are $m$ such $n$'s.

Hence
$$\sum_{n\ge2}a_n=\sum_{m\ge2}\frac1{m\left(m+1\right)}=\sum_{m=2}^\infty\left(\frac1m-\frac1{m+1}\right)=\frac12$$
and
$$\sum_{n\ge3}a_n=\frac12-a_2=\frac12-\frac1{12}=\frac5{12}.$$

Comment: Thanks for editing my question and then answering it! That really helped.